# Maximise the equation which consists of sums of products then performed modulus by a number

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I need a formula to calculate the maximum sum of products of variable and constant and the whole sum will be then performed a modulus by some number.

X = (C1*x1 + C2*x2 + C3*x3..... )%M, we have to maximise 'X' here, the values of Ci and M is given, all xi are variables (non-negative integers, zero included), in short I can say we have to vary the xi's such that we get maximum possible X, for example

X = (10*i + 3*j)%18  (here i and j are variables i.e. non-negative integers)

answer :- X = 17 (take j = 1 and i = 5)

Does any formula exists to find the maximum possible value of X ?

sorry if you didn't understand the question (my English is not good), if you have any doubts ask in the comments section

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is clearly about maths, not programming.

Comment: a person good in algorithm can answer it that's why I posted it here

Answer (score 1):

If there is a C coprime with M, then there exists an x such that Cx = M - 1 (mod M); set all other x to 0 and set the one corresponding to our special C to the required value. You can't do better than M - 1 (mod M).

Otherwise, if there are two coprime C, say C1 and C2, then it is possible to obtain any sum greater than (C1 - 1)(C2 - 1) - 1 (look into the coin problem, or the Frobenius number); since there must exist some number greater than this congruent to M - 1 (mod M), this is as good as you can do; set all other x to 0 and find the x1, x2 required to obtain M - 1.

Otherwise, find the minimum greatest common divisor by comparing first all the C with M directly, and second all C with each other. Let this minimum greatest common denominator be called m. Then, it is possible to get to M - m (mod M) using the above methods with modification. However, it is not possible to get to M - 1 or anything higher than M - m (mod M), since all numbers have a common factor.

To actually find the numbers in these cases, I'd think identifying the case first; then, following the strategy (either 1 or 2 non-zero terms) simply iterate over the possibilities. Since we have narrowed it down to one to two terms this isn't terrible. There might be a smarter way to accomplish this... if something more sophisticated than checking possibilities is needed please comment and I'll revisit this.

UPDATE

The comments suggested that the handling of the third case - of no coprime coefficients - was incorrect, and it is incorrect. Consider the case C1 = 14, C2 = 21, M = 6. The method outlined above finds the minimum pairwise GCD to be 2 and says the maximum attainable is 6 - 2 = 4; however, you can get 5 (mod M) simply by taking x1 = 1 and x2 = 1. Maybe what really has to be done to get the right answer is to consider all pairwise GCDs and apply the same reasoning to these. That is, our pairwise GCDs are 2, 3 and 7. By the solution to the coin problem for n = 2, that means that by combining each pair we can get any number that's a sufficiently large multiple of these GCDs. This means that, modulo M, the GCDs themselves are attainable; so we can recursively apply the above solution to the pairwise GCDs until ALL pairwise GCDs share a common term (then my original case analysis is correct); OR, one of the pairwise GCDs becomes 1, in which case the answer is M - 1.

Note that it's probably possible to keep track of the recursion and cases along the way to reconstruct the correct answer in terms of the original Cs. Left as an exercise.

UPDATE:

Based on comments, I will now attempt to apply this (fixed?) method to a real example.

```
M, C1, C2 = 385, 42, 30
GCD(M, C1) = 7
GCD(M, C2) = 5
GCD(C1, C2) = 6

  7 and 5 are coprime so we can get any number greater than (7-1)(5-1)-1
  any number greater than 23 is obtainable
  384 = 2*[7] + 74*[5]

  7 is obtainable
  7 = 46*[42]

  5 is obtainable
  5 = 13*[30]

  combining, we get
  384 = 2*[7] + 74*[5]
      = 2*46*[42] + 74*13*[30]
      = 92*[42] + 962[30]
      ~ 92*C1 + 192C2
```

Comment: I think you miss a case: when all Ci are not pairwise coprime and are not coprime with M but with a different GCD in each case. Ex: C1=2.3.5, C2=3.7.11, M=5.11.13

Comment: @fjardon It's definitely possible; can you explain what the right answer is for your example and compare that to the answer my method produces? I'll definitely agree that what happens when there's not a pair of relatively prime Cs or C/M is murkier than what happens otherwise.

Comment: I don't know, I solved the same cases than you but got stuck on this one...

Comment: @fjardon It looks like my answer gives a max of 712 for this (M = 715) since the smallest GCD among pairs of Cs and C/M is 3 and 712 = 715 - 3 = 5*11*13 - 3. Values of x that work are 56 and 2; 30*56 + 231*2 = 1680 + 462 = 2142 ~ 712 (mod 715). In this case, we can clearly see any sum will be a multiple of 3, and this is definitely the biggest multiple of 3 less than 715; in general though if the smallest pair is between C/M it might be harder to see this method is correct. I could attempt a proof that these cases are sufficient, maybe it could be done satisfactorily.

Comment: @fjardon I did miss a case, you are right :) Let C1 = 14, C2 = 21, M = 6. Then the smallest GCD among any pair is 2, but you can get 5 (mod M) by simply choosing x1 = 1 and x2 = 1. Updating answer to reflect this.

Comment: "our pairwise GCDs are 2, 3 and 3" -  Isn't GCD(14, 21) 7? I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Yes, you're right, let me edit to correct this.

Comment: @Patrick87With your example of C1,C2,M = 14,21,6 then this is a silly starting point. You can assume that all C are < M. If they are greater than M then you can just subtract M until they are less than M without changing the final result. That makes your example actually be C1 = 2, C2 = 3 which are coprime and thus it is obvious you can reach the max of 5. It occurs to me that you may also need to include inverses when searching for your co-primes. ie if you have M = 13 and a C = 2 then you can replace that C=2 with C=11 because 2a mod 13 = 11*(13-a) mod 13...

Comment: @Chris That's fair, but you could choose M = 36 or M = 66 or something and I think you'll get a similar counterexample without the inherent silliness. Regarding the inverses thing - I'm not sure I follow. Do you have a specific counterexample in mind that would illustrate this failing? Note that if C = 2 and M = 13, we're in the simplest possible case already... although I imagine you chose these simply to illustrate the point and I'm having a hard time seeing the bigger picture.

Comment: @Patrick87: I see what you mean. About M=36 in your example. For mine I think if you consider the following: M,C1,C2 = 385,42,30. Each of those three numbers have factors in common with every other (385=5*7*11, 42=2*3*7, 30 = 2*3*5). However the inverse of 42 is 385-42=343=7*7*7. This has no common factors with 30 so since they are coprime I assert that you can get a total of 384. From some calculations elsewhere I believe that 42*7+30*80 mod 385 = 384. However on seeing your edit I think that might already take it into account for this example since my GCDs are all coprime with each other...

Comment: @Chris Yes by Frobenius / coin problem for n = 2, using each pair you can get all sufficiently large multiples of their GCD; module M, this means you can get the GCD itself. If the GCDs of different pairs are coprime, then since we can get those (modulo M), we can apply Frobenius / coin problem with n = 2 on the pair of relatively prime GCDs to show we can get M - 1. I think if we record our steps along the way we can deduce what the original coefficients should be. I will try that on your most recent example in a fresh edit.